# IE8 asp.net navigation cancelled error on postback

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, dns, postback

In our company, we have bought a web application that we are testing in the intranet zone. We are using IE 8.

Basically, on a particular page, there are a few buttons, and one of them populates a fairly big gridview.

Then as soon as I click on another button that causes a postback, I immediately get a 'web page navigation cancelled (DNS Error).

At first I thought it could be a problem with the URL being too long, but it's not the case.

Then, the vendor performed the same actions on his computer, and it worked correctly. Clearly, this is not a problem with the website itself, but probably a configuration with IE8.

Unfortunately, we cannot use or test with Firefox or IE9. We are stucked with IE8.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answers on [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/dns-error-server-cannot-be-found-ever-on-ie8-on-my/d5422e90-7ca7-4548-af7a-5984adecd50d), specifically the one by SpritX. Many reasons this could be happening and there are a few solutions in that discussion you can try.